# Move a single element above the keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I would like to move a single element (relative layout) of my layout above the software keyboard when an editText is focused.

I've tried to set `android:windowSoftInputMode` with `adjustResize` in my manifest but as I seen in many other stackoverflow questions it works only with the entire Activity.

So, is it possible to move a single element above the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following sample helps.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="EditText1" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="EditText2" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            <EditText android:id="@+id/editText4" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="EditText4" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/editText5" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="EditText5" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/editText6" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="EditText6" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/editText7" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="EditText7" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/editText8" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="EditText8" />
            <EditText android:id="@+id/editText9" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="EditText9" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout style="@android:style/ButtonBar" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

http://www.androidpub.com/?document_srl=1703090&mid=android_dev_qna&comment_srl=1704523&rnd=1704523#comment_1704523